# Semantic doubt over a problem statement?

Tags: java, command-line

You should have a single command-line argument representing number of  objects you must generate for the user.

Just wanted to make sure that I got this one right.

Does this mean we should pass the params to the main method?

Comment: I think this *is* programming related and not one of the plz-send-me-teh-codez questions. This is just like the famous "How do I move the turtle" question and should not be closed, just because everyone would know the answer to that question.

Comment: Agreed. Albeit homework related, this is a valid question.

Comment: ask your teacher, he knows better than us

Comment: what are those candidates your assignment is talking about?

Comment: It is an assignment dealing with semaphores. There are N canditates and they order drinks and they have to let another guy know when the drinks get consumed. Once they get consumed, the other guy fills the drinks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your Java program needs to be invoked from the command prompt, say for example, MyProgram.java is a source file which contains the `main()` method, you compile this using the javac compiler by doing `javac MyProgram.java` at the command prompt to get the MyProgram.class file. This .class file is then invoked by doing `java MyProgram` at the command prompt to run your program.

What you need to do here is pass parameters to the `main()` method when you run your program simply by doing `java MyProgram <your params go here>`

Comment: In your code, those command line arguments are in the `String[]` passed to `main()` which is usually called `args`.

Comment: thanks for explaining clearly. I am pretty comfortable with java, but somehow, despite having written many programs, I never came across this type of basic problem.

Answer (score 4):

A **command-line argument** is something passed to the executable on the command line at runtime:

```
someprog foo bar baz.txt
```

So, it would take only one of these:

```
someprog foo
```

Since this is Java, you would pass it after the class name:

```
java myclass 3
```

Answer (score 3):

means your program should accept a single argument (parameter), most likely an int when invoked from the command line. I am **not** a java guy but i am guessing something like

```
java -jar myprog.jar 8
```

I say with kindness that if that escapes you, you need to brew a pot of coffee and open the book to chapter one.

Good luck.

Comment: I think you mean: java -jar myprog.jar 8

Answer (score 1):

When you run your application via the command prompt, you give it a number.

For example, if your application is called "ExerciseOne", and you want it to process 10 candidates, you must run it by typing

```
ExerciseOne 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Your main method has one argument: an array of Strings. args[0] will contain the first argument of your command line. You don't have figure out by yourself what number it represents, the Integer class has a method called parseInt that can do that for you.